# #define to include header file c++

Tags: c++

I feel myself a bit lost about the syntax for `#define`. For example, we can include `header` file as

```
#include "header.h"
```

But I did some logical experiments and found out that

```
#define header
```

leads to the same result. Consequently,

```
#define header_H
#define _header_H_
```

Could you, please say what is the difference between all of them? This whole idea to include file through `#define` looks interesting, providing that we have `#include`. And what does this sign `_` mean? I did not find its definition in preprocessor tutorial.

Comment: What do you mean "leads to the same result"? I seriously doubt that.

Comment: I mean that the code builds, as if header file is included

Comment: http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf

Comment: Does the code also build without either a `#define` or `#include`? If so, it doesn't really mean much, does it?

Comment: @haavee wrong language.

Comment: Of course, it does not build without them. I use VS 13 and can give a code as an example

Comment: How can it build if header includes function declarations used in .cpp?

Comment: I doubt that. Are you sure that's the only header included? Maybe you're including the header indirectly (i.e. included in another header that you're including).

Comment: `#include "header.h"` is C. `#include <header>` is C++ ... ;-)

Comment: @haavee also incorrect.

Comment: @haavee, your comment _must_ be downvoted. You can `#include <stdio.h>` in C++, for example.

Comment: @haavee you're mistaken. Both are C *and* C++. In fact, the C book you've linked uses `#include <header.h>` extensively.

Comment: @haavee: The difference between double quotes, ", and angle brackets, <>, with the `#include` directive is where to search for the *file*.  They are both valid in C and C++.  By your definition, if I create a file "apple.hpp", I will need to place it in angle brackets like this: `#include <apple>`, which is wrong.  How does the compiler know to include "apple.h" or "apple.hpp" or "apple.hxx"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "header.h"
```

This is replaced by the compiler with the code of `header.h`.

```
#define header
```

This just defines a 'mark' (not sure how to call it). It can be used in some code like that

```
#ifdef header 
    puts("It is defined!");
#else
    puts("Oh no!");
#endif
```

The underscores can be used in a variable's names and also in the defines. They don't have any meaning except the fact that many functions used in system libraries start with an underscore. So, writing a function called `_exit` will lead to lots of problems as there is an important system call called like this.

If `define` works like `include` in your case, than I can guess your compiler's drunk or you have `#include "header.h"` somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 4):

My assumption is that your confusion is why the include guards work with any name. The `_` (underscore) has no significance* other than it is a valid identifier, the name `header_H` is just designed to be unique so that the contents of your header are only compiled once and doesn't cause issues with duplicate symbols. While it would be bad practice, your include guard could be `#define a`, `#define abc` or any other valid alpha numeric combination that is not reserved.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H //<- as I mentioned could be anything valid and not reserved
#define HEADER_H //<- Now this must be the same to work properly
    ... // defines
#endif
```

* *Prefixing with an underscore is discouraged as it reserved to the implementation.*

Comment: The _ does make a difference. And he's not asking about include guards.

Comment: I will agree that is an assumption, and I'm editing now to include implementation reserved notes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `#include` will do just that, include the file into your project. However, C++ compilers are not smart enough to understand if you use `#include samefile` twice, so as a result, it will add the same file twice. This is were `#define` comes in. You use `#ifndef __FILE__` if it has not been included already and `#define __FILE__` so that the compiler knows it has been included.